# preg_match: undefined offset

Tags: php, preg-match, undefined, offset

This gives me an error like "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in \index.php on line 12".

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

$i=0;
while($i<=3){
    foreach($arr as $value){
        //get data
        $content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/$value');

        preg_match("^ y: ....^", $content, $match);
        $string = $match[$i];

        $i++;

        echo $value;
        echo $string;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$match` doesn't work the way you are using it — it contains subpattern matches. I suggest you have a good read of the [PCRE documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) before revising your code.

Comment: you don't need the while loop

Answer (score 0):

backslash before : (and maybe second ^?)

Comment: i think there's no problem with the regex :\

Comment: The error: $match is an array filled by preg_match. $match[0] will be the total match, $match[1] the first parenthesised expression (group) and so on. Your $i loop assumes there are four groups. I would have expected the $i loop inside the foreach, or maybe even $match[0] or so. ^ is begin, maybe the second should be $ (end), and with "a:{3}" one would indicate a repetition of `a` three times. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
print_r($arr);
```

to inspect the array $arr, it may help you to find what is wrong.

It seems to be referring to - `$arr[0]` as `$arr[1]`

Comment: it doesn't seem to have problems with the array